# Strange behaviour on Black Ops Multiplayer

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops

Sometimes when I'm playing Black Ops, my movement is distorted, in that it moves side to side, backwards and forwards. When it started happening I thought it was my network connection, so I reset all my configurations so that my NAT wouldn't be disrupting the communications. However, it still happens intermittently. If I let go of the controls, it still happens.

I'm worried that it may be because of some hacks that people are using, but I can't see anything obvious, i.e. nobody is running away with the game, and I don't know of any hacks that are available on the PS3.

Has anybody experienced anything similar or can anybody suggest a way of preventing this from happening?

Comment: Maybe it's your controller thats stuck? :p

Comment: Still sounds like something network related and you being out of synch with others. Could be a network hack/lag something, no experience with it though, just a guess.

Comment: @RafaelCelerier definitely not the controller, works absolutely fine on every other game

Comment: @AlasdairCM Well if it is not the controller then the most logical thing i can think about is it is indeed network related. Now this might not be your fault but more the servers fault. But this is all but guesswork really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the room is lagging out. It used to happen to me all the time if its how you say it is. The room is losing the connection, even if your connection is great, the host could have a bad connection and your character jumps around the screen like you are saying.